# Accessing Methods of ArrayList with Multiple Object Types in

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got a superclass that multiple different subclasses extend from. Each subclass then has specific methods for that concrete class that other subclasses may not follow. ie:

- public class NMEA    ... methods that all subclasses hold
- public class GPGGASentence extends NMEA .. has some specific method to this type
- public class GPGPSSentence extends NMEA .. has some specific method to this type

I create a subclass by checking the first few letters in the String and then switching between the possibilities.

```
ArrayList<NMEA> sentences = new ArrayList<>();

switch (s.split(",")[0]){
     case "$GPGGA":
          sentences.add(new GPGGASentence(s));
          break;
     case "$GPGPS":
          sentences.add(new GPGPSSentence(s));
          break;
}
```

I'm now getting to the point I want to loop through this ArrayList. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
for(NMEA nmea : sentences){
     if(nmea instanceof GPGGASentence){
          system.out.println((GPGGASentence) nmea).someSpecificMethod());
     }
 }
```

I was wondering if their is some nicer way of doing this.

Comment: That is a reg flag.  You need to code to interfaces.  Spend some time reading about design patterns.

Comment: I recommend removing the specific methods from the subclasses and instead overriding an abstract method in each of the subclasses.

Comment: Your superclass should implement all the possible methods, you will call them, and they might just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to as suggested change the NMEA class into an abstract class and list all the methods within that class and then override them.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from writing `abstract class`/`interface` and declaring all the methods, this is what you can do to improve the redability of the code:

- Create an `enum` of all the possible class types
- Write a method that returns enum value for object
- Use `switch` with different cases.

Here is an example. Declare enum like below:

```
private enum ClassType {
    NMEA,
    GPGGASentence,
    SomeOtherType,
    Unknown;
}
```

Now, a method to return `type`:

```
private ClassType getClassType(NMEA object){
    ClassType type = null;
    try{
        type = ClassType.valueOf(object.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        type = ClassType.Unknown;
    }
    return type;
}
```

Now, use it with `switch` inside a `for` loop:

```
for(NMEA nmea : sentences){
    switch(getClassType(nmea)){
    case ClassType.NMEA :
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

If a new `Impl` class gets added in future (or name of any class is changed), all you need to do is to add an `enum` value and a `switch case`.